# hy3ファイルを変換（デコンパイル）したい

Tags: file

**hy3ファイル**をエディターで開いたところ、１６進数にコンパイルされたものがでてきました。
元のデータは不明ですが、おそらくほぼor全て数字と思われます。（大雑把ですいません）
これを**元の状態に変換して見る**方法、または**hy3ファイルを触った方がいれば**お知恵をお貸し下さい。

追記(2024/03/24)
Windowsだとファイルを使えるソフトがあったのですが、Macユーザなので、使えずにいました。
ファイルの中身は日付、整数、小数の羅列です。
また、現在目的の操作をこのファイルを使わずに実現しできたので、あまりそれ以降触ったり調べてないです。ご協力ありがとうございました。

Comment: 聞き馴染みの無いファイルタイプですが、恐らくは特定のアプリでサポートするデータのようです。 https://www.filesuffix.com/ja/extension/hy3 ファイルの仕様が分からない事には、好き勝手に何でも変換できるわけではありません。

Comment: 質問者さんがお使いの hy3 ファイルについて、どのような場面で利用したものなのか質問文を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。インターネット上にも情報が乏しいファイルフォーマットもしくは拡張子のように思います。HyTek Meet Manager で使われることがあるというのは散見されますね。

Comment: Windowsにあるという「ファイルを使えるソフト」が何かわからないと、あなたが言うhy3ファイルがどのアプリ用のどのようなファイルなのかがわかりません。「ファイルを使えるソフト」の名前を明記してください。